# Long or String for Norwegian birth number

Tags: java, string, long-integer

I have a class called Person, which looks something like this:

```
public abstract class Person {
    private String birthNo;
    ...
}
```

Norwegian birth numbers are 11 digits long, and are constructed from an algorithm described [on this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#Norway). I can't use int, seeing as most birth numbers exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

I've heard that when deciding whether you should use a String or integer for storing numeric values, you should ask yourself: *Do I need to perform mathematical operations on this value?*

I am doing this on `birthNo`, but a lot of the operations become somewhat easier with String's `charAt(int i)`. If I were to store the birth numbers as a long, I would have to use modulo and division to get the desired digit:

`int ninth = Character.getNumericValue(birthNo.charAt(8));`

vs.

`int ninth = birthNo / 100 % 10`

The mathematical operations I want to do are getting the person's gender (female if 9th digit is even), and validating the birth number with an algorithm similar to the ISBN ones.

Another argument to use String is that some birth numbers will have leading zeros, and therefore not be "11 digits", if stored as a long.

What is the preferred solution? Long for mathematical operations, or String for convenience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Norwegian eleven digit Birth Number is assigned at birth or
>   registration with the National Population Register. The register is
>   maintained by the Norwegian Tax Office. It is composed of the date of
>   birth (DDMMYY), a three digit individual number, and two check digits.

I'd be tempted to create a `BirthNumber` class with a `LocalDate` for date of birth and either `int` or `String` values for the other two fields, dependent upon what you're doing with them. That way you could parse the birth number in your constructor and obtain the values you need using instance methods.

Based on the comments below, here's how I might wrap the date of birth:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class DNumberLocalDate {

    private final LocalDate localDate;
    private final boolean isDNumber;

    public DNumberLocalDate(LocalDate localDate, boolean isDNumber) {
        this.localDate = localDate;
        this.isDNumber = isDNumber;
    }

    public DNumberLocalDate(LocalDate localDate) {
        this(localDate, false);
    }

    public int getDayOfMonth() {
        return isDNumber ? localDate.getDayOfMonth() + 40 : localDate.getDayOfMonth();
    }

}
```

Comment: One issue I can see with that solution is that not all birth numbers are able to be represented as "dates". See the third item in the list in [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#Norway).

Comment: That sounds like a complicated system. Perhaps you could store D-numbers differently, maybe use some kind of a flag, or create a wrapper class for `LocalDate` that handled this for you.

Comment: I think I'd have the person class have `getBirthNumberAsLong`, `getBirthNumberAsString`. Or a `BirthNumber` class with `asLong`/`asString` methods. How you store it then doesn't matter.

Comment: I'll include an example of how I might consider wrapping the date of birth to work with D-numbers.

Comment: @RobertBain I think you meant for the getDayOfMonth()-method to return 40 + `localDate.getDayOfMonth()` if it is a D-number.

Answer (score 2):

The birth number is an ID but is not a number: you don't want to use mathematical operations on it. In your example you want to split the ID to find some information, you don't want to divide it. For this reason you should use `String`. An other reason are leadings zeros as you said, a number could not handle it.

However, you can use `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` for big numbers.

Comment: I am using mathematical operations to get the person's gender (female if 9th number is even, male otherwise), and to validate the birth number.

Comment: @MartinMJ you could get the gender by getting the character and checking its value modulo 2. This would neglect direct mathematical operations on the ID.

Comment: I see. I mistakenly thought @Happy meant not doing any mathematical operations whatsoever.

Comment: I agree with Happy, this person ID number is really a *label* and not a number, so `String` would be more suitable. What if the ID starts with a `0`? You can't capture that if you store it as a `long`. Just like phone numbers are really labels and not real numbers, and shouldn't be stored in a numeric type.

Answer (score -1):

A string can represent more then an Basic Integer (leading 0 and more )
Therefore u should store it as String and set it private.
U can define 2 geter methods 1 for each type.
Never Access vars directly if u want to have code which is oop.
Greetz